# Strava Api bad request

Tags: python, django, strava

I need to get segments on Istanbul so I have to send geographical coordinates 
I'm using Postman and Google Chrome

```
https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/explore?bound=41.008238, 28.978359&access_token=
```

and we get Bad Request error. 
Here stravalib
https://pythonhosted.org/stravalib/_modules/stravalib/client.html#Client.explore_segments

https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Segments-exploreSegments

Comment: How are you sending your request?

Comment: With Chrome URL bar and Postman.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify bounds as the latitude and longitude for two points describing a rectangular boundary for the search: southwest corner latitude/longitude,northeast corner latitude/longitude.

So the request will be something like this:

```
www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/explore?bounds=41.002403,28.963957,41.016741,28.986722&activity_type=running
```

It is better specify `activity_type` parameter to request only running/cycling segments.

Last but not least: remember that the request only returns the top 10 segments matching a specified query. So if you want every segment of Istanbul you need to send different requests at different latitude/longitude and then mix the results.